# Python. Перезагрузка модуля

Tags: python, python-2.x, модули

**modul_1.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/python

class Example():
    print 'it is example'
```

**modul_2.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/python

from modul_1 import Example
from imp import reload

reload(modul_1)
```

> ```
>      linux:/home/user # python ./modul_2.py  
>      it is example
>      Traceback (most recent call last): 
>       File "./modul_2.py", line 6, in <module>
>        reload(modul_1)
>      NameError: name 'modul_1' is not defined
> ```

Используемая версия "python 2.7".
Не могу понять, почему появляется данная ошибка.
Прошу помочь.

Answer (score 1):

Этим кодом вы не создаете переменную для модуля `modul_1`

```
from modul_1 import Example
```

Добавьте перед `reload(modul_1)` следующую строку

```
import modul_1
```

Comment: Более того, перегрузка `modul_1` модуля не перегрузить существующий класс Example.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, ошибка в том, что нужны кавычки.

**modul_1.py**

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

class Example():
    print 'it is example'
```

**modul_2.py**

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

from modul_1 import Example
from imp import reload

reload('modul_1')
```